# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I'm trying to `bundle update` i get this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
```

In Gemfile:
    actionpack (>= 4.2.5, ~> 4.2)

```
railties (>= 4.2.5, ~> 4.2) was resolved to 4.2.5, which depends on
  actionpack (= 4.2.5)

railties (>= 4.2.5, ~> 4.2) was resolved to 4.2.5, which depends on
  actionpack (= 4.2.5)

railties (>= 4.2.5, ~> 4.2) was resolved to 4.2.5, which depends on
  actionpack (= 4.2.5)

strong_parameters (~> 0.2.3) was resolved to 0.2.3, which depends on
  actionpack (~> 3.0)
```

Comment: this question shows absolutely zero effort in trying to resolve the problem yourself, it's just a copy and paste of an error message.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can arise if you update the Rails version (for example from 4 to 5), and you have included certain gems locked to a specific version which still depend on an old ActionPack version from the old Rails version. Then bundler says..

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack"
```

..because the new rails version wants to use the new ActionPack gem, but one of the gems wants to use the old ActionPack gem.

Answer (score 1):

You should've include the `Gemfile` in the question.

Anyway, in Rails 4.x `strong_parameters` gem is not required. If you have that in your gemfile, remove it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the strong_parameters gem. Strong parameters is part of rails 4, the gem allows that feature to be backported to rails 3.x

This is partly to help rails 3.x users to  migrate to rails 4 and I think it may have been used earlier to prototype how strong parameters should work (by allowing people to use it without switching to rails edge)